# Convert lat long to Place Name

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to convert the latitude - longitude to Address(Place Name).

I think it can be done using CLGeocoder on iOS 5.0 and MKReverseGeocoder (Depricated in iOS 5.0) on iOS < 5.0.

My application need to support from iOS 4.0 onwards.

Can anybody suggest a way to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the API is deprecated does not mean that you cannot use it on iOS 5. It is still going to work, but may be removed in a future version without warning. So to keep the compatibility, you could perform a check if the `CLGeocoder` class is available and use the appropriate implementation:

```
Class clGeocoderClass = NSClassFromString(@"CLGeocoder");
if (clGeocoderClass) {
    // iOS 5. Use CLGeocoder
} else {
    // iOS prior to 5. Use MKReverseGeocoder.
}
```

So you won't run into any problems if `MKReverseGeocoder` is removed in the future, because the `CLGeocoder` class will be preferred. Devices running iOS versions prior to 5 are unavoidably going to fall back to `MKReverseGeocoder` anyway, which is no problem on old versions.